# Post array is empty in ASP/PHP on IIS 8

Tags: php, forms, post, asp-classic, iis-8

I am moving some of my companies old websites from Win 2008 webserver SP2 64-bit with IIS 7 to Win 2012 R2 64-bit with IIS 8. Everything seemed to be going smoothly until I tried a form page. GET works but POST throws a 500 error '80004005' on the page that Requests the form variables (regardless of method i.e. Request("x"), Request.Form("x") etc). Somehow the post data disappears on the way.

Some more info:

-There is nothing wrong with my code, this happens to all my old forms as well as super simple test forms.

-The same things happen when I submit a PHP-form. Post comes back empty.

-Handler mappings allow the GET, HEAD, POST verbs so that is not the problem. I have checked that basically everything in IIS is configured like on my old server and I am using the same web.config files so nothing should have changed there.

-I have read and tried suggestions to change the application pools to Classic mode and No managed code and tried to enable 32-bit. It does not help.

I have seen several people with the same or similar problem online but I have not found any working solution. It seems like something in IIS checks and empties the post array before it reaches ASP/PHP but I have no clue how to disable that. Isn't there anyone who has a solution for this please?!

Edit:
I don't know which part is unclear, basically post data is not coming through in ASP or PHP on my new IIS 8 server. PHP gives a 200 code and just returns nothing, ASP throws a 500 error. Once I post data the error is thrown as soon as I try to access the Request.Form object. Something in IIS destroys the post data object before it even reaches my script. The closest to an explanation that I have found online is that some http module in IIS reads the POST data and leaves it empty when it reaches ASP/PHP. But I don't know how to find or turn off that module if that is the cause so I really hope that someone can help!

Comment: can you please re-edit your question a bit? hard to read

Comment: '80004005' is a database error - is that because a value is blank? Do you have any URL rewriting or redirection going on?

Comment: Thanks for your input. I think 80004005 is basically an unspecified error saying that the script can't access the data. In this case it is the post data or rather the entire Request.Form object that can't be accessed. I am using the same rewrites as on my old server but even disabling them all does not make any diffference.

Comment: In your web.config(if you are using one) , is `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` set to true?

Comment: Thanks for your input! I have a web.config but I did not have this attribute there. I tried to set it to both true and false but unfortunately it did not make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Not much of an answer but I solved the problem by reinstalling the server from scratch. It was decently quick since they are both VPS. On my new server POST works fine for both ASP and PHP. I have really tried to compare them side by side, step by step, to see what can have triggered the problem but so far I have not found it. However since it was solved by the reinstall it is not a generic problem, something must have gone wrong during the first install. I will update this if I found out what triggered the problem.